# Accessing combined UIMA Ruta Annotations in Java

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I have a problem accessing combined Ruta Annotations.

My Annotations are based off a prior Module that generates NormalizedNamedEnitites (NNEs) and Marks them according to a ruleset, which works just fine:

```
NormalizedNamedEntity{REGEXP(NormalizedNamedEntity.concept.identifier,"XXX") -> MARK(XXX)};
NormalizedNamedEntity{REGEXP(NormalizedNamedEntity.concept.identifier,"YYY") -> MARK(YYY)};
```

Then I proceed to combine those two in a new Annotation:

```
(XXX){-> CREATE(CCC, "YYY" = YYY, "XXX" = XXX)};
```

Which also works very fine.

In my IDE (Eclipse), I can access those new Rules in the Ruta Editor View and everything is perfectly working.
But after that I want to access the "encasing" Annotation and add all "nested" Annotations to an array, which I just can't find out how. I'm pretty lost in the documentation and am hoping someone out there has this already done and can help me out on this case.

Again: I'm using Java (1.8).

Thanks a lot!

**Edit: Further Information**

- Encasing Annotation: *Med*
- Nested Annotations: *Name*, *Dose*, *Scheme*

Sample Text:

```
Paracetamol 40mg daily
```

Annotations made (with the help of prior Models/Modules, see above):

```
Paracetamol 40mg daily
Name------- Dose Scheme
```

Now I want to introduce a encasing Annotation called "Med", which, in case all three nested Annotations are present will encase those.

The Type "Med" has each of the nested Types as a accessible Feature defined.

Now I want to access firstly the Med Annotations (which isn't the problem for me here) and then each nested Annotation (on which I got no idea how to do - yet).
I'm still ploughing through the documentation of UIMA to find a hint.

Comment: Can you please extend your question with information which annotation is encasing and which are nested, how the types are defined (e.g., feature ranges), and on what text passage the example should work. Normally, you can simple match on the encasing annotation type and set its features with a type expression if the feature range is an FSArray.

Comment: @PeterKluegl: Added more information. I will add more as soon as I can get my hands on the TypeSystem definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to access nested annotations. Currently, I prefer something like the following:

```
DECLARE Name, Dose, Scheme;

// some mocked annotations
"Paracetamol" -> Name;
"40mg" -> Dose;
"daily" -> Scheme;

DECLARE Med (Name name, Dose dose, Scheme scheme);

(n:Name d:Dose s:Scheme){-> CREATE(Med, "name" = n, "dose" = d, "scheme" = s)};

DECLARE Test1, Test2, Test3;

Med.name{-> Test1}; 

m:Med ->{
    m.name{-> Test1};
    m.dose{-> Test2};
    m.scheme{-> Test3};
    };


FOREACH(med) Med{}{
    med.name{-> Test1};
    med.dose{-> Test2};
    med.scheme{-> Test3};
}
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*